# slow queries: a practical solution to this example?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just downloaded my slow query log
and one query that is frequently shown is

```
select * from feedback_to_user
left join user_tb on  feedback_to_user.feedbacker_id = user_tb.user_id
left join user_to_photo on  feedback_to_user.feedbacker_id = user_to_photo.user_id
where  feedback_to_user.feedbackee_id="7375"    
AND user_tb.admin_review = "1"  
AND user_tb.user_published = "1"    
AND user_tb.user_active = "1"        
AND user_tb.user_verified = "1"             
order by  feedback_to_user.ftu_id DESC;
```

so how do I fix it? either the syntax or in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Have you done an `EXPLAIN` to see what indexes (if any) the query is using?

Comment: what's EXPLAIN? i'm not a mysql expert...

Comment: Just run the query again and prefix EXPLAIN to it: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ...`. MySQL will explain to you what it does and what it expects from the various pieces of the query. Add the result to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick already suggested, you should use EXPLAIN.

But in general, you should consider these points (in query inspection order):

> select * from feedback_to_user...

*Is it really necessary to select **all** fields with that asterisk?* Maybe you only need a few. There's little point in having huge blocks of data whizzing around just to be ignored and/or discarded; best not to select them in the first place. Also, this way MySQL will better estimate actual retrieval costs, and might well optimize better the query (see later on covering indexes).

> left join user_tb on  feedback_to_user.feedbacker_id = user_tb.user_id

*Do you expect not to be any user in feedbacker_id, so that the row will have all user_tb fields to NULL, and do you need that row nonetheless?* If NOT, then use a straight JOIN (not a LEFT JOIN). Improvements might be negligible -- but they still come for free (by the same token, if you're in doubt, then leave the LEFT JOIN be).

> left join user_to_photo on  feedback_to_user.feedbacker_id = user_to_photo.user_id

Same as above. Do you only need rows **with** a photo? If so, JOIN.

> where  feedback_to_user.feedbackee_id="7375"
>   AND user_tb.admin_review = "1"
>   AND user_tb.user_published = "1"
>   AND user_tb.user_active = "1"
>   AND user_tb.user_verified = "1"

Are all these fields *VARCHARs* or are they *integers*? If you store only integers (and the occasional NULL) in there, having an integer data field will yield nice dividends. If you use them as flags, then TINYINT might (and it might not) further improve performances. Also bitfields could be investigated.

However, if you have lots of these queries, you'd do well to create an INDEX on `user_tb` with the fields you're querying on:

```
CREATE INDEX user_db_flags 
ON user_tb(admin_review, 
           user_published,
           user_active,
           user_verified);
```

You can experiment adding to it the `user_id` field you use in the JOIN too:

```
-- remove previous index
ALTER TABLE user_tb DROP INDEX user_db_flags;

-- add index
CREATE INDEX user_db_flags 
ON user_tb(user_id,
           admin_review, 
           user_published,
           user_active,
           user_verified);
```

And an INDEX on feedback_to_user:

```
CREATE INDEX feedback_to_user_id 
        ON feedback_to_user(feedbacker_id, feedbackee_id, ftu_id);
```

You might also experiment exchanging those positions:

```
CREATE INDEX feedback_to_user_id 
        ON feedback_to_user(feedbackee_id, feedbacker_id, ftu_id);
```

This will help MySQL get rid of redundant information and quickly find the information you need.

If one of the JOINed table were to have only very few, very small, fields, and the selection was very precise (such as is the case with feedback_to_user where you select a single feedbackee_id), you might employ a "covering index", i.e. an index that has the fields you search on in the first positions, and the fields you need in the next positions. Especially if the table has many other and bigger fields, this allows MySQL to query *on the index* without ever loading the table at all. If the index is sufficiently smaller than the table, the speed gains could be huge. Otherwise, **don't bother** -- maintaining indexes has a cost, too.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `EXPLAIN` to analyze it, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Unfortunately we do not know your table structures row counts and indices, but you should start with optimization reading this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html

Comment: where do i do that? how? do i go to phpmuadmin in the QUERY tab?

Comment: In phpmyadmin you can run your query and should find an option "Explain SQL", click it.

You should get some rows with columns like "select_type", "table", "type". If the "type" of a row with select_type "PRIMARY" is "ALL", this is very bad. "INDEX" is only bad. There is a good chance you can optimize it.

Comment: i tried a query and used the "explain" link the select_type = SIMPLE, but type = ALL

Comment: see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html

select_type = SIMPLE: Simple SELECT (not using UNION or subqueries)
type = ALL: A full table scan...

So please add indexes, this would be a good start for this example.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html